# Why do the buttons not work?

Tags: android-layout, android-button

can someone explain what's wrong?

I want it to work like this:

Three buttons at the top of the screen. When I press button1 it should show make the  #1 visible. When I press button2 it should show  #2 and hide  #1 and #3 and so on... I have different layouts inside each .

***FRAGMENT CLASS:***

```
 public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        Fragment1 f = new Fragment1();

        return f;
    }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_musikteori_symboler, null);

    final Button button1 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    final Button button2 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    final Button button3 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.symb_id3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

***LAYOUT:***

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dynamik"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Toner"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Takter"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/symb_id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            layout="@layout/fragment_musikteori_symb_dynamik" />


        <include
            android:id="@+id/symb_id2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            layout="@layout/fragment_musikteori_symb_toner" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/symb_id3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            layout="@layout/fragment_musikteori_symb_takter" />




        </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error...

```
01-24 14:38:51.341    5039-5039/com.myapp.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.okramuf.musikteori, PID: 5039
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.test/com.myapp.test.testapp_main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.okramuf.musikteori.musikteori_main.onCreate(musikteori_main.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: for first button you set `View.GONE` to all cases, is it correct? (only note, not solution :)) .. and you dont need this part: `} switch(v.getId()){` for button 2 and button 3 part - so, you can use code like: `switch(v.getId()) { case x: some_code; break; case y: some_code; break; }`

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with the code, but why not explain what's wrong with it? as in, what is happening? What do you see? If, for instance, the only issue is that button one doesn't work, you should check @Atiris ' comment. If there is more, why not explain?

Comment: Nothing happens when I press the buttons, that's the problem. I'm trying his/her solution right now.

Comment: @Atiris It still doesnt work :(

Comment: You have no onClick listeners set, see @Atiris answer.

Comment: you should reindent and add language tag to your code for coloring

Answer (score 2):

I don't see button registration for click action.
And some others bugs :)
Look on tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

You need something like this:

```
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

or, if you implement on click listener, then you can use

```
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You use `@+id/button1` in XML layer .. and then `R.id.symb_id1` in code,
I think this is wrong, then fix `View.GONE` and `switch` commands..
try some tutorials and then do it again.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post, but when I use your code it force closes, even withouy any action attached to the button.

Comment: I have added that now

Comment: Ok, and what is on this line with error: `com.okramuf.musikteori.musikteori_main.onCreate(musikteori_main.java:51)`? Or try remove any code from your Fragment1. Then it open/start application and you can see buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If found a solution here:

[Android Developers - Performing Fragment Transactions](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)